# Load plain text in bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

How can I load a plain text inside a Bootstrap popup via javascript? I want to set pTitle text but innerHtml doesnt work.

```
var $modal = $('#preview_dialog');
var $title = $modal.find('#pTitle');
$title.innerHtml = ($("#Title").val());

<div id="preview_dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 600px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="left-inner-addon">
                            <span id="pTitle" class="form-control-static"></span>
                             <input class="form-control" id="pTitle2" type="text" class="input-medium" />        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the code to some event - for example `keyup` if you want title to be changed "on live" or `change` if you want title to change when input's value will change.

You can also use `html()` function to change the value of `<span>` content

```
$('#pTitle2').on("keyup", function() {
  $('#preview_dialog #pTitle').html( $("#pTitle2").val() );
});
```